# Adobe Illustrator to Microsoft Office

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, file-format

I hope you can help?  if an image is used in illustrator that will be used for office products what is the best format?

Comment: Best format depends on usecase, scenario and particular graphic and exactly which office program you use. Powerpoint is different from word in this regard.

Comment: If you have found any of the answers below to have answered your question please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer.  If the answers do not answer your question please make an [edit] seeking clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little outdated here but I'm not currently using the latest version of office.

But as I recall, Office was pretty bad working with vector files. The EMF and WMF was very bad maintaining the shape. So if you do not need an editable object, probably the best option is exporting as a transparent PNG with a decent size (px) or at 100% size at let us say 150 PPI, if you are going to use the image as a "floating" shape.

Also if the shape has gradients, you need to flatten them in a bitmap.

You can try EPS for simple shapes.

At the end you need to try and error. Depending on the specifics of the image you could loose nodes or some characteristics of the image or not. It is not going to take more than 5 minutes do some tests on your specific image.

Comment: EPS works only tentatively, but is the only format capable of CMYK that you can insert in word. Great care must be taken so that word does not rasterize the format **very badly**, so no scaling of EPS or rotating inside word or the EPS file is broken forever. Likewise you need take care when printing that you have a PS capable printer, or print to acrobat. Do not use the conver to PDF options inside word or again it breaks.

Comment: Well, I think if you think in terms of cmyk you would not think in terms of Word. Any Rgb image would be good for a office and home printer.

Comment: You would be wrong, theres nothing worng in trying to get your printer not to print rick black text in images and not in body text. You'd be surprised how many thesis workers have requested me to do this for them

Comment: Hum... You are probably right. I normally flee away in thoose cases n_n

Answer (score 1):

**RGB PNG24** is generally the best option for any Microsoft Office application.

You can *try* vector formats, but they tend to get destroyed if the Office document, whatever it is, is opened on any other system. And often they break on the same system that created the Office file.

Office is *dumb* when it comes to commercial print standards.. it loves RGB... and PNG offers transparency over jpg... so RGB PNG is often best. Barring that.. a jpg.

In fact, if you use the Export for Microsoft Office command in Illustrator.. that's what is created, a PNG.

Comment: Office is just retarded in this sense. You can copy paste simple shapes into power point tough and make it native office vectors (by ungroup) which is stabler in many cases than nay other method.

Comment: @joojaa true, But even then they can break at times. Kind of depends upon the artwork overall.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Illustrator has a "Save for Microsoft Office" setting and it has worked well for me. It exports as a transparent PNG at 150 resolution. Screenshot is from version CS6.

[image]